# Android - Refresh data in an AlertDialog?

Tags: java, android, android-alertdialog

So, if I create an AlertDialog like so:

```
AlertDialog.Builder b = new AlertDialog.Builder();
b.setItems(MyStringArray, MyListener);
b.create().show();
```

And then I want to update the items in the list, i.e. MyStringArray has changed to have more or fewer items. I can't seem to find a way to do this. So far, I've tried getting the ListView from the AlertDialog, but I can't seem to get .setAdapter to work. Is this the right approach, or is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I haven't tried this out myself, but from all the other apps I've built I'm pretty sure this will solve your problem.

Instead of using setItems, try using the `setAdapter()` method and pass in an `ArrayAdapter` that has been initialized with the data from your `Array` of `String`.  Then, when you know that the data has changed, you can use `getListView()` to get your View object and from there call `getAdapter()` so that now you're working directly with the dataset.  You can clear it, and re-initialize it if you like, or just add / remove the items as you like.  From the adapter object, if you call `notifyDataSetChanged()` it should trigger a re-draw using the new data set that you just supplied to the adapter.

Hope that helps you out.  Let me know if it doesn't.

DSC

Comment: I'm still a bit of a novice when working with these dialogs. Should I keep the DialogInterface.OnClickListener as the OnClickListener, or use a View.OnClickListener as I might with a normal Listview?

Comment: Kinda stupid of me to ask that when I could just try it. Looks like DialogInterface.OnClickListener is the way to go.

Answer (score 3):

If you are like me and you would like to use default adapter for example for multichoice items, then there is also a way.

Just as with any other adapter just update the string array object, get adapter from the dialog instance, cast it to appropriate adapter and invalidate it.

```
AlertDialog.Builder b = new AlertDialog.Builder();
b.setItems(MyStringArray, MyListener);
AlertDialog instance = b.create();
instance.show();

// Later when you need to update
MyStringArray[0] = "puf";
ListView list = instance.getListView();
// Now according to whether you used cursor or array for supplying items to the builder
// you have to cast adapter to either CursorAdapter or ArrayAdapter
ArrayAdapter adapter = (ArrayAdapter)list.getAdapter();
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

[You can find out more here.](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/1.5_r4/com/android/internal/app/AlertController.java#AlertController.AlertParams.0mAdapter)

Answer (score 0):

This is how I did it in Kotlin:

```
AlertDialog.Builder(context).apply {
   val actions = arrayListOf("aa", "bb")
   val onItemClickListener = DialogInterface.OnClickListener { dialog, which ->
       // code
   }
   val adapter = ArrayAdapter(requireContext(), 
       android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, actions)
   setAdapter(adapter, onItemClickListener)

   executeGetRequest() {
      actions.add("cc")
      adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
   }
}.show()
```